# Input 0 of layer "conv2d_24" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am currently attempting to make my first deep learning model which is meant to detect fire and smoke in images.

The code works up until I attempt to fit the model where it throws the error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_8" (type Sequential).   
Input 0 of layer "conv2d_24" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 1)
```

I loaded my images through glob:

```
fire = glob.glob('1/*.png')
Nonfire = glob.glob('0/*.png')
```

then turned them into lists to merge them into a pandas data frame.

Then I split my data into training and testing like this

```
test_size = int(len(df) * 0.1) # the test data will be 25% of the entire data
train = df.iloc[:-test_size,:].copy() 
test = df.iloc[-test_size:,:].copy()
print(train.shape, test.shape)

x_train = train.drop('label',axis=1).copy()
y_train = train[['label']].copy()

x_test = test.drop('label',axis=1).copy()
y_test = test[['label']].copy()
```

and then built and compiled the model like this

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(128,(2,2),input_shape = (196,196,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(1,activation= "sigmoid"))
#Model description
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and all of the code works without error.

However, when I attempt to fit the model like this

```
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),epochs = 30,batch_size = 32)
```

it throws the above error and I am unable to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an issue with your `x_train` data. What is the result of this print if you execute it right before calling `fit()`?

```
print(train.shape, test.shape)
```

In your first layer you set the input shape of `(196, 196, 3)` + the batch size -> four dimensions. But you're giving to `fit` something like this `(1)` + the batch size (the None in the error message) -> two dimensions.

So you probably just have an error in your train shape. It is hard to figure it out without having your dataset, but with some debug you should be able to solve it.

**Update:**

I've built this pre-processing script for your data. I've tested it on some dummy images, however it should work as you need:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#reads the names of the dataset images
fire_images = glob.glob('1/*.png')
nonfire_images = glob.glob('0/*.png')

print(fire_images)
>> ['1/1.png', '1/0.png']
print(nonfire_images)
>> ['0/1.png', '0/0.png']

# loading the images as np.array

X = []
y = []

for image in fire_images:
  X.append(cv2.imread(image))
  y.append(1)  # assign label 1 to fire_images 
for image in nonfire_images:
  X.append(cv2.imread(image))
  y.append(0)  # assign label 0 to nonfire_images 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

#importing keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalMaxPooling2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

#Building model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(128,(2,2),input_shape = (196,196,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(2,2),activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dense(1,activation= "sigmoid"))
#Model description
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), validation_data=(np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)),epochs=30, batch_size=32)
```

I've used `train_test_split` from `sklearn.model_selection` to split the dataset. Note that the argument `random_state` is important. When you load the data, the fire and non fire images are in two different folders, so the array presents the first rows with fire data, and last rows with non fire data. If you split the dataset without shuffling you'll get your test data with only non-fire data and you'll get low results from your training.

Your problem was basically at the start of your script. You were creating a dataframe with, inside the column `images`, the names of your files, and not the array of the actual data.

Comment: print(train.shape, test.shape) gives the result(12, 2) (1, 2)
(12, 2) (1, 2) which doesn't seem right to me as the dataset has around 600 images total. Here is the link to the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/atulyakumar98/test-dataset?resource=download

Comment: Exactly, you made some mistake while preparing your train and test data. You should aim at having a shape for your x, like `(num_examples, 196, 196, 3)`.

Comment: I just checked how many images were imported from the dataset and it shows that only 9 images total were pulled. However, my syntax seems to be correct. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Can you add all the code from when you start downloading the dataset, to ` model.fit()`? So I can try reproducing the issue

Comment: Stackoverflow wont let me add the entire code so I pasted it into a google doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kWwsJFsWgmvPXo-gjZTXFZX3NV73p7zPRq8LoMEDv4I/edit?usp=sharing

Also I just want to say thank you so much for helping me with this!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247321/discussion-between-haamed-rahman-and-claudia).